# Chrome extension can't load .json file

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load my manifest.json file to my Chrome extensions, but it is giving me this error: `cant'n load JavaScript file „_locales/YTplugin.js“`

This is how my manifest.json looks:

```
 {
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "YouTube trending extension",
  "version": "0.1",

  // Recommended
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "YT extension",
  "icons": {},

  // Optional
  "author": "Josef Reischig",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {},
  "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],"js": ["/_locales/YTplugin.js"]}]

}
```

My `YTplugin.js` is stored in _locales folder together with my manifest.json file. Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

try the following path

```
"content_scripts": [{"matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],"js": ["../_locales/YTplugin.js"]}]
```